# jQuery.ajax post returning whole html of the page called from onchange event from a select tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I want to post a value using ajax from a js file to a phtml file in magento,
basically the problem is on success it will alert with the html code of the page instead, starting from the doctype until the end.
I want to get the correct value since I need to use it in one of the magento function called through the PHP.

here is the function I called on change:

```
function getsingproduct(id)
{
var str = 'product' + id;
var currentselecteditem;
ele = document.getElementById("product" + id);
currentselecteditem = ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].value;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        curr_item: currentselecteditem
    },
    success: function (data) {
        jQuery('#testing').text(data);
        alert('data ' + data);
    },
});
}
```

Comment: Where are you posting the data? No `URL` is set!!

Comment: I want to post it to the same page ,that's why, I think if I leave the url out, it will default to current page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some javascript code:

````
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "new_prob_submit.php", 
            data: {
    curr_item: currentselecteditem
},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                 alert(data);
            }
        });```
````

Comment: can I just post it to the same page?